# How to form a mosaic picture by using GIMP or another app. by using other pictures?

Tags: photos, gimp

How can I create a mosaic picture by using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or another app. by using other pictures like below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [AndreaMosaic](http://www.andreaplanet.com/andreamosaic/)

[Here is a guide](http://www.engadget.com/2004/10/19/how-to-make-your-own-photo-mosaics/) that [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com) did about five years ago on this software.

---

AndreaMosaic, a free project to create digital art using images and computer software. With AndreaMosaic you can create your own photographic mosaics made with your own pictures. A photo mosaic is an image composed of many tiled photos.

Comment: is there any plugins to make this by using GIMP 2.6?

Comment: I don't know about using GIMP, but why would you want to if a tool like this can do it for you, just import when done... and please change your question back - a bit annoying that I answered your question with software that works, then you changed your question to make my answer invalid!

Comment: don't worry I accepted your comment as an answer.But I am looking for the best.

Comment: Thanks, Also, I looked for ages, and even 5 years on, this software is the best for mozaics!