# Make a mosaic picture out of 900 images

Tags: linux, images, photos, image-editing, pictures

I have ~ 900 pictures (mostly photos) of varying sizes.

Now I want to create one big picture that includes all 900 pictures in a small thumbnail-like resolution. The tool should automatically resize the thumnails so that everything fits. All pictures should be added next to each other, so there should be no border/padding.

*Each* picture should be included exactly *one* time! (however, it would be okay to omit a few so that there is no empty space)

I'm looking for a tool (**FLOSS**, for **GNU/Linux**) that can do the job.

I tried [Metapixel](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/schani/metapixel/), but

- it needs an input image that should be "resembled" by the thumbnails, and
- it only uses a selection of all pictures.

I found [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/), but couldn't get a result yet, because my system was unresponsible for hours after starting it. Maybe there are some tweaks?

[AndreaMosaic](http://www.andreaplanet.com/andreamosaic/) is [recommended in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/60391/151741), but it's not FLOSS (and needs Wine to run it on GNU/Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to at least resize all the images with a script. [On howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/) you can find a small guide of its uses. You can install it from the repo with apt or with Software Center on Ubuntu.

To place all of them on a single big one, once resized, as you said, montage should work. It is part of imagemagick so maybe it is not working because you didn't install the full imagemagick package?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using a combination of the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) tools and [GIMP scripting](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).

You will need to read the docs and adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

What about of [wosaic](https://code.google.com/p/wosaic/)? It can use local pictures to recreate the one you need.