# How to create massive image mosaic/collage?

Tags: windows-8, image-editing

I am artist looking for advice for a project I am planning. I basically want to take around 20,000 images and stitch them together to form a large mosaic. However I don't want to create a larger image out of these small images, I want them to be randomly placed. I'm imagining each image will be reduced to about 4x4 mm and then printed out on a scroll of textile or material. The length of the scroll is the variable. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe these image could be placed randomly according to some color range constraints ? I mean, i could setup the program to have a red color dominant at left top corner, white dominant in the center, blue dominant at middle bottom and so on ? This way you can draw an big image with tons of small ones!! you know, like this Bob Marley poster made with lot of small pictures : http://www.allposters.fr/-sp/Bob-Marley-mosaique-Affiches_i1386709_.htm :)

Comment: I edited this to not just be a request for software to do this for you, as software requests are off-topic.  What have you tried so far? What graphic editing tools do you use/have available?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to form a mosaic picture by using GIMP or another app. by using other pictures?](http://superuser.com/questions/60389/how-to-form-a-mosaic-picture-by-using-gimp-or-another-app-by-using-other-pictur), http://superuser.com/questions/511834/make-a-mosaic-picture-out-of-900-images?lq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/313035/how-can-i-take-hundreds-of-smaller-images-and-create-one-big-tiled-image